# NSArray initWithObjects: Memory Leak

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Here is my code:

```
    - (void)viewDidLoad{
[super viewDidLoad];

self.authorList = [[NSArray alloc] 
                   initWithObjects:@"Christie, Agatha", 
                   @"Archer, Jeffrey", nil];

self.title = @"Authors";
```

}

I am getting memory leak at line where i am allocating and init the array authorlist. I tried to put autorelease on authorlist but it says that "Object sent- autorelease sent too many times". I am still learning memory management.

Gracias.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The setter method for `authorList` will retain the array so you need to release it immediately after calling it:

```
NSArray *list = [[NSArray alloc] 
                initWithObjects:@"Christie, Agatha", 
                @"Archer, Jeffrey", nil];
self.authorList = list;
[list release];
```

Or you can autorelease it:

```
self.authorList = [[[NSArray alloc] 
                   initWithObjects:@"Christie, Agatha", 
                   @"Archer, Jeffrey", nil] autorelease];
```

Comment: thanks. i put autorelease wrongly. Trojan can u explain me why [authorlist autorelease] separate in next line doesn't work ?. Thanks again

Comment: @bloodwing It's because you need to release the array you have just created, not the instance variable.  When you call `self.authorList = list` the setter for `authorList` retains the array, and without the (auto)release you then have a retain count of 2, hence the memory leak.

Comment: isn't that variable has reference to that array ?

Comment: @bloodwing Yes it does, however it needs to be allowed to control the lifetime itself.  Your issue was that you created an array, passed ownership to the setter method and then didn't relinquish your ownership of it.

Comment: ok thanks a lot. Just last thing, when i put [authorlist autorelease] separate then it said that autorelease was called too many times. So Does this means that setter method already implements one autorelease behind ? Thanks. Sorry for bothering u much :D

Comment: @bloodwing That's because the `authorList` getter method will perform something like `return [[_authorList] retain] autorelease]` to give you a convenient autoreleased object to use for the scope of your method.  Calling `[authorList autorelease]` is not needed; you just need to worry about the objects you allocate.

Answer (score 0):

Did you wrote dealloc method in your Class?

If you did not use ARC  http://cocoa-touch.blogspot.ie/2008/09/memory-management-on-iphone.html

Comment: no i didn't wrote dealloc. But i wrote to check, so when i call release on my array i get "incoorect decrement of reference count that is not owned at this point by caller"

Answer (score 0):

You should not allocate the property object directly.

You should allocate like this :

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad{
      [super viewDidLoad];

       NSArray *tempArray = [[NSArray alloc] 
               initWithObjects:@"Christie, Agatha", 
               @"Archer, Jeffrey", nil];
       self.authorList = tempArray;
       [tempArray release];


      NSString *titleString = @"Authors";
      self.title = titleString;
      [titleString release];
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
 self.authorList = [[[NSArray alloc] 
               initWithObjects:@"Christie, Agatha", 
               @"Archer, Jeffrey", nil] autorelease];
```